# scala-regexp: split string into array of two following words

Tags: regex, scala

I need to split string into the array with elements as two following words by scala:

`"Hello, it is useless text. Hope you can help me."`

The result:

`[[it is], [is useless], [useless text], [Hope you], [you can], [can help], [help me]]`

One more example:

```
"This is example 2. Just\nskip it."
```

Result:
`[[This is], [is example], [Just skip], [skip it]]`

I tried this regex:

`var num = """[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+""".r`

But the output is:

```
scala> for (m <- re.findAllIn("Hello, it is useless text. Hope you can help me.")) println(m)
it is
useless text
Hope you
can help
```

So it ignores some cases.

Comment: ignore the regex break the code on SPACE and use a for loop to join them. Taught a comment would be quicker thats why

Comment: Capital letters are preserved or adjusted to lowercase?

Comment: @jwvh preserved. It's my mistake. I should edit it

Comment: Try [`"""(?=\b(\w+\s+\w+)\b)""".r.findAllMatchIn(s.replaceAll("""(?U)\W+""", " ")).map(_.group(1))`](https://ideone.com/UREK0L)

Comment: What should happen for "I don't like Mike's over-use of apostrophes! (Why is that?)" (i.e. embedded non-letter, parems,  trailing question marks etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split on the punctuation and digits, then split on the spaces, then slide over the results.

```
def doubleUp(txt :String) :Array[Array[String]] =
  txt.split("[.,;:\\d]+")
     .flatMap(_.trim.split("\\s+").sliding(2))
     .filter(_.length > 1)
```

usage:

```
val txt1 = "Hello, it is useless text. Hope you can help me."
doubleUp(txt1)
//res0: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(it, is), Array(is, useless), Array(useless, text), Array(Hope, you), Array(you, can), Array(can, help), Array(help, me))

val txt2 = "This is example 2. Just\nskip it."
doubleUp(txt2)
//res1: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(This, is), Array(is, example), Array(Just, skip), Array(skip, it))
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First process the `string` as it is by removing all escape characters.

```
scala> val string = "Hello, it is useless text. Hope you can help me."
val preprocessed = StringContext.processEscapes(string)
//preprocessed: String = Hello, it is useless text. Hope you can help me.
```

> OR

```
scala>val string = "This is example 2. Just\nskip it."
val preprocessed = StringContext.processEscapes(string)
//preprocessed: String =
//This is example 2. Just
//skip it.
```

Then filter out all necessary chars(like chars, space etc...) and use `slide` function as

```
val result = preprocessed.split("\\s").filter(e => !e.isEmpty && !e.matches("(?<=^|\\s)[A-Za-z]+\\p{Punct}(?=\\s|$)") ).sliding(2).toList

//scala> res9: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(it, is), Array(is, useless), Array(useless, Hope), Array(Hope, you), Array(you, can), Array(can, help))
```

Comment: "Hello, it" and "text.Hope" are separated by punctuation marks and should not be in resulting list

Comment: Updated the `filter` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `split` to break the string down into words separated by non-word characters, and then `sliding` to double-up the words in the way that you want;

```
val text = "Hello, it is useless text. Hope you can help me."

text.trim.split("\\W+").sliding(2)
```

You may also want to remove escape characters, as explained in other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I only know Python. I heard the two are almost the same. Hope you can understand

```
string = "it is useless text. Hope you can help me."

split = string.split(' ')  // splits on space (you can use regex for this)

result = []

no = 0

count = len(split)

for x in range(count):
    no +=1

    if no < count:

        pair = split[x] + ' ' + split[no]   // Adds the current to the next

        result.append(pair)
```

The output will be:

```
['it is', 'is useless', 'useless text.', 'text. Hope', 'Hope you', 'you can', 'can help', 'help me.']
```

Comment: I'm sorry. But splitting by space is not the answer. Because punctuation marks are in lists. However, I understand the idea of your answer

Comment: The comma's in list are useless in real life. You can't make use of it whatsoever. Anyway like you said I hope you get the part of the for loop/

Comment: Please don't answer a question about Scala with some code in Python. They are very different languages.

Comment: ok. please. I taught they I heard somewhere they can be used alternatively. That's why. Just wanted the point of the for loop to be explained well.

Comment: @surge10 Your `for` loop is not appropriate for Scala, so your answer is misleading. Please don't answer questions about languages that you do not understand.